How to integrate MEF as an external DI Container into SpecFlow?
The SpecFlow project (https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow) provides an own plupin to integrate AutoFac as an external DI container. There is also a blog entry from the SpecFlow author where he describes how he did it (https://gasparnagy.com/2016/08/specflow-tips-customizing-dependency-injection-with-autofac/). He provided his AutoFac plugin as a template for integrating other DI containers. Unfortunately this article is a little bit outdated.
Is there anybody out there who has already build an integration for MEF (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/mef/)?

SpecFlow has a small guide for this: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Context-Injection.html#custom-dependency-injection-frameworks - it basically shows you how to register the Autofac plugin. Have you considered looking at the autofac plugin source code and adapt it to MEF?

Looks like Autofac integration is baked into SpecFlow now: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/tree/master/Plugins/SpecFlow.Autofac.SpecFlowPlugin
